# any object detection within ROI using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, object, detection

i'm writing a code for collision detection or warning system . like car reverse assistance system . my problem is how to find any obstacle regardless of color or shape in my region of interest . im using OPENCV 3.3 and PYTHON . i'm attaching a pic so u can understand what i want to do . also the camera is mounted to the vehicle . so background subtraction may not be the right option here..
please help
[image: roi is the green yellow and red lines combined area]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cars, such system depends on **ultrasonic sensors** to detect the distance from objects.

It's nearly impossible to write a robust solution to detect the distance from *any obstacle* using just one camera, unless you have a predefined list of objects to be detected.

As pointed out by @api55, you can have some success by changing your approach to use **stereo vision** to be able to create a 3D representation of the environment. This will give the depth sense that is missing on your current approach.

Comment: I agree with you, but I will add that if you have 2 cameras it is plausible (up to certain degree) with stereo to get distance of objects to the camera and have a start for what he wants to do. With mono and just computer vision it is not possible.

Comment: @api55 I saw the sample image in the question and totally forgot to mention that there is a totally different approach you can do with stereo vision. Thanks for bringing it up!